# Android Image Representation

Tags: android, image, pixel

I'm trying to access the raw pixel data of an image in Android.
The code looks something like this:

```
   Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile("image.png"); 
   // assert valid input
   if ((bitmap.getConfig() == null) || bitmap.getConfig() == Config.ARGB_8888)
      throw new Exception("bad config");

  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight());
  bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);        
  return buffer.array();
```

How are the pixels in the linear 1D `buffer.array()` stored?

1. First element is top-left pixel or bottom-left pixel (or something else)?
2. Row-major (row after row) or column-major (column after column)?
3. Channel order ARGB or BGRA?
4. Row-major or column-major for each channel separately?
5. Something else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the offset into `buffer.array()` for a given pixel `x`,`y` in an image of size `width`x`height` with `bytesPerPixel` bytes per pixel, use this formula:

```
offsetForPixel = (y * width + x) * bytesPerPixel
```

In other words, the first element in the array is the top-left pixel, and the following elements are row-major. All data for a pixel are stored in adjacent bytes and are not spread out based on channel. This is the answer to 1, 2 and 4 above. Now let's discuss 3, which is where things become complicated.

What you get with Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer() is the raw bitmap data representation used by Android's low-level drawing library [skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/). This has three significant consequences:

- The channel order depends on endianness
- The channels are premultiplied with alpha
- *How channels are packed into containing data types is configurable*

The last point makes it awkward to use `Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer()` at all if you want to inspect individual pixels, because you simply can't know how skia has been configured to pack channels. As an experiment, try this code:

```
int inputPixel = 0x336699cc;
int[] pixels = new int[] { inputPixel };
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, 1, 1, Config.ARGB_8888);
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
bm.copyPixelsToBuffer(bb);
Log.i("TAG", "inputPixel = 0x" + Integer.toHexString(inputPixel));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    String byteString = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(bb.array()[i] & 0xff);
    Log.i("TAG", "outputPixel byte " + i + " = " + byteString);
}
```

When I run that, I get this output:

```
I/TAG ( 1995): inputPixel = 0x336699cc
I/TAG ( 1995): outputPixel byte 0 = 0x14
I/TAG ( 1995): outputPixel byte 1 = 0x1f
I/TAG ( 1995): outputPixel byte 2 = 0x29
I/TAG ( 1995): outputPixel byte 3 = 0x33
```

We can see that we are dealing with big endian, that the in-memory representation is pre-multiplied and that channels have been re-arranged from ARGB to RGBA (motivated in the skia source code by that that is the same in-memory representation as OpenGL).

If you want to read the pixel data, I suggest you use [Bitmap.getPixels()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) instead. There is some copying involved, but at least the API specifies how the returned data is formated.